# Loading environment variables from YAML file (using include_vars) in Ansible

Tags: ansible, environment-variables

I am trying to load variables from a YAML file to be used as environment variables in a later task of the same playbook. This is what I am doing:

1. Template host vars in YAML format:

```
- name: builtin | template | template host variables file
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: templates/django/hostvars.j2
    dest: "host_vars/{{ inventory_hostname_short }}.yml"
    mode: 0640
    output_encoding: "utf-8"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

This is producing the following file:

```
--
# Host variables to be set as environment variables in tasks that need it
POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "<password>"
POSTGRES_USER: "dbuser"
POSTGRES_DB: "dbname"
POSTGRES_HOST: "dbhost"
POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
POSTGRES_SSLMODE: "verify-full"
POSTGRES_SSLCA: "/etc/ssl/certs/ISRG_Root_X1.pem"
POSTGRES_APPNAME: "myproject"
DJANGO_SITE_NAME: "mysite"
DJANGO_SITE_PASSWORD: "mypassword"
DJANGO_SITE_USER: "myuser"
DJANGO_SITE_ID: 2
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY: "<very-long-and-random-secret>"
[..]
```

2. Use `include_vars` to load the vars into the playbook:

```
- name: builtin | include_vars | load host vars
  ansible.builtin.include_vars:
    file: "host_vars/{{ inventory_hostname_short }}.yml"
    name: envvars
```

3. Later on the playbook, check that the variables are there:

```
- name: builtin | debug | print variable 'envvars'
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: envvars
```

This is working as intended (apparently) and a list of KEY: value variables is being printed, such as:

```
TASK [builtin | debug | print variable 'envvars'] ***************************************************************
ok: [django1.mydomain.com] => {
    "envvars": {
        "DJANGO_DEBUG": 0,
        "DJANGO_LOGS_DIR": "/opt/django/logs",
        "DJANGO_MEDIA_BASE": "/opt/django/media",
        "DJANGO_SECRET_KEY": "<very-long-and-random-secret>",
        [..]
```

4. Use `django_manage` to update the database schema:

```
- name: community.general | django_manage | update database schema
  community.general.django_manage:
    command: migrate
    settings: myproject.settings
    project_path: "/opt/django/src"
    virtualenv: "/opt/django/venv"
  become: true
  become_user: django
  become_method: su
  environment: "{{ envvars }}"
```

This, unfortunately, is failing. Django is complaining that it cannot find the `SECRET_KEY` environment variable, which it should build based on one of the variables in the abovementioned list (especifically, `DJANGO_SECRET_KEY`).

Incidentally, if I run the following task, nothing is printed out:

```
- name: print environment variables
  ansible.builtin.command: env
  become: true
  become_user: django
  become_method: su
  environment: "{{ envvars }}"
```

And I don't understand why. I've tried to debug using -vvv and they are being sent by Ansible though the SSH connection (at least so it seems).

Any hints on what bit I am doing wrong?

**EDIT 1**

I've changed the tasks list file where I use `django_manage` into the following code:

```
- name: builtin | shell | capture DJANGO_ environment variables
  debugger: on_failed
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: "env | grep DJANGO_"
  register: out
  environment: "{{ envvars }}"
  become: true
  become_user: django
  become_method: su

- name: builtin | debug | pinrt content of out.stdout
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: out.stdout

- name: builtin | debug | print variable 'envvars'
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: envvars

- name: community.general | django_manage | populate the static subdirectory
  community.general.django_manage:
    command: collectstatic
    clear: yes
    project_path: "/opt/django/src"
    virtualenv: "/opt/django/venv"
  become: true
  become_user: django
  become_method: su
  environment: "{{ envvars }}"
```

The second and third tasks both print the values of the variables (the first one from the `env | grep DJANGO_` command sent via `shell` and the second is the value of the `envvars` variable which is being sent via the `environment:` directive.

This is the error of the last task:

```
TASK [builtin | shell | capture DJANGO_ environment variables] *************************************************************************************************************
changed: [django1.donmain.com]

TASK [builtin | debug | pinrt content of out.stdout] ***********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [django1.django.com] => {
    "out.stdout": "DJANGO_SITE_USER=mysite\nDJANGO_MEDIA_BASE=/opt/django/media\nDJANGO_SITE_NAME=mysite\nDJANGO_SITE_ID=2\nDJANGO_SECRET_KEY=<very-secret-key>\nDJANGO_LOGS_DIR=/opt/django/logs\nDJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings.production\nDJANGO_DEBUG=0\nDJANGO_STATIC_BASE=/opt/django/static\nDJANGO_SITE_PASSWORD=mypassword\nDJANGO_SITE_VERSION=57a2f3c168d86243f03809e5d02a0f50a8fa892e"
}

TASK [builtin | debug | print variable 'envvars'] **************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [django1.domain.com] => {
    "envvars": {
        "DJANGO_DEBUG": 0,
        "DJANGO_LOGS_DIR": "/opt/django/logs",
        "DJANGO_MEDIA_BASE": "/opt/django/media",
        "DJANGO_SECRET_KEY": "<very-secret-key>",
        "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE": "myproject.settings.production",
        "DJANGO_SITE_ID": 2,
        "DJANGO_SITE_NAME": "mysite",
        "DJANGO_SITE_PASSWORD": "mypassword",
        "DJANGO_SITE_USER": "myuser",
        [..]
    }
}

TASK [community.general | django_manage | populate the static subdirectory] ************************************************************************************************
fatal: [django1.domain.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["./manage.py", "collectstatic", "--noinput", "--clear"], "msg": "\n:stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/opt/django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py\", line 204, in fetch_command\n    app_name = commands[subcommand]\nKeyError: 'collectstatic'\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/opt/django/src/./manage.py\", line 22, in <module>\n    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)\n  File \"/opt/django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py\", line 381, in execute_from_command_line\n    utility.execute()\n  File \"/opt/django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py\", line 375, in execute\n    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)\n  File \"/opt/django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py\", line 211, in fetch_command\n    settings.INSTALLED_APPS\n  File \"/opt/django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py\", line 57, in __getattr__\n    self._setup(name)\n  File \"/opt/django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py\", line 44, in _setup\n    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)\n  File \"/opt/django/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py\", line 107, in __init__\n    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py\", line 127, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1030, in _gcd_import\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1007, in _find_and_load\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 680, in _load_unlocked\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 790, in exec_module\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed\n  File \"/opt/django/src/black_pearl/settings/production.py\", line 3, in <module>\n    from black_pearl.settings.common import *\n  File \"/opt/django/src/black_pearl/settings/common.py\", line 301, in <module>\n    path_app = import_module(app).__path__\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py\", line 127, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'None'\n", "path": "/opt/django/venv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin", "syspath": ["/tmp/ansible_community.general.django_manage_payload_l53eeo4g/ansible_community.general.django_manage_payload.zip", "/usr/lib/python39.zip", "/usr/lib/python3.9", "/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload", "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages", "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages"]}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
django1.domain.com    : ok=14   changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Nothing is printed out."***

A: Register the output if you want to see it. For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - command: echo $DJANGO_DEBUG
      register: out
      environment:
        DJANGO_DEBUG: 0
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  out.stdout: '0'
```

This should work for you. Step by step add the complexity to your code and isolate the problem. For example, the playbook below should display the environment at the remote host

```yaml
- hosts: test_11

  vars:

    env:
      DJANGO_DEBUG: 0
      DJANGO_SITE_NAME: mysite
      DJANGO_SITE_PASSWORD: mypassword
      DJANGO_SITE_USER: myuser
      DJANGO_SITE_ID: 2

  tasks:
    - shell: env | grep DJANGO_
      register: out
      environment: "{{ env }}"
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout
```

Comment: Hi, Vladimir, and thanks for your reply. Your example works, indeed. While redoing the whole thing and splitting it into different files, I think I found out that "hostvars" is not a variable name you can use.

Comment: For future reference, this is how I split the example to look like my usual structure, and got it to work:

Comment: The `envtest.yml` playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: django

  tasks:
    - import_tasks: tasks/test/vars.yml
    - import_tasks: tasks/test/env.yml
```

Comment: The `tasks/test/vars.yml`:

```yaml 
- ansible.builtin.include_vars:
    file: host_vars/test.yml 
    name: env
```

Comment: The `host_vars/test.yml` file:

```yaml
---
DJANGO_DEBUG: 0
DJANGO_SITE_NAME: mysite
DJANGO_SITE_PASSWORD: mypassword
DJANGO_SITE_USER: myuser
DJANGO_SITE_ID: 2
```

Comment: And the `tasks/test/env.yml` file:

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: env | grep DJANGO_
  register: out
  environment: "{{ env }}"
  become: true
  become_user: django
  become_method: su

- ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: out.stdout
```

Comment: After this successful test, I went and tried it in my current, big playbook. It works up until I print the `cmd: env | grep DJANGO_` bit from the `out` variable I registered.

Comment: Then the next task, which does exactly the same but using the `django_manage` module, fails because `./manage.py collectstatic --clear --noinput` cannot find the environment variables.

Comment: I have edited the initial question with the task list being executed where one can see that your code, adapted, is working, but when using the `django_manage` module, it does not. Maybe it's because when the module is excuting `./manage.py` the environment variables are not being passed over?